# Firebase (using re-base) "fetch" method

Tags: reactjs, firebase, es6-promise

I'm using the [`re-base` library](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) to interact with a Firebase app; I'm looking to get a piece of data using the `fetch` method. The example in the documentation just uses `console.log` and doesn't return a value, so I don't know how to gain access to the data being fetched.

For instance, I'm trying to set a variable to the result of `fetch`, then use that in a stateless functional component's `render` method:

```
// app/components/CompanyCard/index.js
let subtitle = helpers.getCompanyName(props.company);

return (
    <div className="Card">
      <div className="Card-body">
        <p className="Card-subtitle">{subtitle}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
);


// app/config/api.js
const Base = Rebase.createClass('https://###.firebaseio.com');
export let helpers = {
  getCompanyName: (id) => {
    return Base.fetch(`/companies/${id}/name`, {
      context: {},
      then: (data) => data
    })
  }
}
```

I've tried using both `return Base.fetch...` and just `Base.fetch...` but neither works; `{subtitle}` is just empty. I get `undefined` if I log `subtitle`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get at the result of the `fetch` method using `re-base`?

Comment: I don't think Base.fetch will return a value. you might try a callback in `getCompanyName`  to assign the `subtitle` variable instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creator of re-base here.

You're tying your hands down by forcing a stateless functional component. Because you have a "side effect" like fetching data from Firebase, it's probably best to have a component that handles doing that fetching, then once you have the data to pass that to your stateless functional component to render. Something similar to this.

```
function Card (props) {
  return (
      <div className="Card">
        <div className="Card-body">
          <p className="Card-subtitle">{props.subtitle}</p>
        </div>
     </div>
  );
}

const CompanyCard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount () {
    getCompanyName(this.props.company)
  },
  getCompanyName (id) {
    Base.fetch(`/companies/${id}/name`, {
      context: this,
      then: (subtitle) => {
        this.setState(subtitle)
      }
    })
  },
  render () {
    <Card subtitle={this.state.subtitle} /> 
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. Seeing the "side effect" comment helps break apart that logic into separate concerns.